# Audio/Video Record and play in php

Tags: php, audio, video, save, recording

I want to implement video/Audio recording and saving in php. I have found many plugins for this but unable to find a cross browser plugin which will work in all browsers like safari, IE, mozilla, chrome etc. That plugin should also work in ios.

Wowza is working on all browsers but does not work on ios. Please help me to find suitable plugin.

Comment: Plugins are stopping for all browsers soon. I've never heard of Wowza releasing a browser plugin (do you have a link of what you used?). Maybe you meant _"I tried many API"_?. Also it's against rules to ask for tools/plugins (since not an advertising website). We volunteer to answer only **problems inside your code**.

Comment: OK I was unaware about this rule.Here is link for plugin [https://www.videowhisper.com/demos/recorder_wowza/]. Also what do u mean by plugins are stopping. does recording audio video will not be supported by plugin?

Comment: Adobe will [stop their Flash plugin](https://venturebeat.com/2017/07/25/adobe-taps-apple-google-facebook-microsoft-and-mozilla-to-kill-flash-by-2020/) in December 2020. Flash plugin does not work on Android and iOS browser (some browser apps like Dolphin or Puffin managed it). To record via web page use (HTML5) WebRTC method. To encode that recording as MP4 (with h.264 video codec) you must install FFmpeg in your web server (if possible) and pass audio/video data (bytes) to it to encode as a video file.

Comment: Sorry not so much WebRTC but [**getUserMedia**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia). See this [**A/V capture tutorial**](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/). It is the captured raw-format data that you now send to FFmpeg to be encode from raw to MP4 format. Since FFmpeg must exist, so you install on a server and access it via PHP. PS: WebRTC is for live chat applications etc (just they too also capture A/V like you want, so I was confused and used same name for different thing)

Comment: WebRTC doesn't work in IE and safari i think.

Comment: If IE/Safari can accept HTML's `getUserMedia` API that's all you need. Don't worry about WebRTC since not making a live chat/game/conference app. Capturing A/V is the easy part. Having an encoder to package as media file is the hard part (about licences, rights, software politics, etc). FFmpeg is free and opensource so no charges.Is used by Wowza and Youtube and Facebook all use it to convert/encode different formats. Download it for your desktop, test it from commandine and see if worth installing in a server too (PHP function sends same commandline commands).